# Horizontal scrolling doesn't show up when I resize browser

Tags: html, css

I am building out a page. I noticed that when I resize the browser to see how it looks in a smaller window, the horizontal scroll bar doesn't show up.

This is the only css code I have for the body:

```
body {
font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
margin:0;
background-image:url(img/paper-footerbg.png);
background-attachment:scroll;
background-repeat:repeat-x repeat-y;
```

}

Here is a link to the page I am building out, http://taghomecaremarketing.com/test/theadamgroup/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css for container div's, remove `overflow: hidden`

`#headerBox, #mainBox, #subBox, #footerBox`

Surely, you will encounter some other problems, but that's the answer ...

Comment: Other problems, meaning that my content will go outside the container? That's why I've been using overflow:hidden, I did forget using visible or auto is better, but someone below is suggesting I remove overflow period. What are the flaws of using it? For for taking the time to help.

Comment: You can learn from these articles about clearing floats and different techniques. I hope this will help.

[css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/),
[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 0):

Or add overflow:auto. or overflow:auto!important;

If that does work and brings up a scroll on the x and y axis. Then best to try overflow-x:auto;

Good luck!

Comment: I would rather use this than using clear: both, left, or right, but I want to see answers on why it should be removed period. Thanks for taking the time to answer though!

Answer (score 0):

You've set it to `overflow: hidden`! This hides the content. Change it to `overflow: auto`, or better still, delete it!

Comment: What is the downside to using overflow? I usually use it for my container div's when I have floating div's and sometimes it shows my content going out of my container. So i use overflow: hidden to get away from using <br style="clear: both;" />